# My Javascript works on one page, but doesnt on another. (code is almost the same)

Tags: javascript, html

I want span to show name of file that going to be uploaded.

```
<input type="file" name="sub" id="files" class="inputfile">
<label for="files">Choose a File</label>
<span id="filename">No File Selected</span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/upload.js"></script>
```

It works fine in code sample below.

```
<input type="file" name="picture" id="files" class="inputfile">
<label for="files">Choose an Image</label></br>
<span id="filename">No Image Selected</span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/upload.js"></script>
```

upload.js

```
$("input[id='files']").change(function (e) {
var $this = $(this);
$("#filename").html($this.val().split('\\').pop());});
```

Both IDs (files, filename) are used just once, so that shouldn't be problem.

**Example snippet:**

```js
$("input[id='files']").change(function (e) {
var $this = $(this);
$("#filename").html($this.val().split('\\').pop());});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="sub" id="files" class="inputfile">
<label for="files">Choose a File</label>
<span id="filename">No File Selected</span>
<!--
<input type="file" name="picture" id="files" class="inputfile">
<label for="files">Choose an Image</label>
<span id="filename">No Image Selected</span>
-->
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's  console?

Comment: Check your browser's console to see any error

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: I found this error in browser's console - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at upload.js:1

Comment: Works for me with whichever of the two html examples provided, but you _cant_ have BOTH on the same page as the script will only ever work on the first.

Comment: Demonstrably works: https://jsfiddle.net/frxum05z/

Comment: So at least there is another change which is not visible here. Maybe you forgot to add jQuery?

Comment: They are used on separated pages :)

Comment: $ is not defined means that jquery isnt available. Have you loaded it? Your script should be wrapped in a doc ready of some sort

Comment: @AdamCintula: `"$ is not defined"` - You didn't include jQuery.

Comment: `$('#files')` is more succinct than `$("input[id='files']")`

Comment: Wow really, I didn't include jQuery. I didnt checked that. Works fine now. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score -1):

Strange, but i haven't error with your code.

May be the cause of all that in the id. If your project very complex, try to use tools like [Web dev Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm). There is a search for duplicate id

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and should probably be a comment.